# Dash draggable param in html.Div

Tags: python, html, plotly

How to use the `draggable` param in Dash's `html.Div`?

from the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/div), we have the below explanation

> `draggable (string; optional)`: Defines whether the element can be dragged.

I thought the param will accept `bool` but its a string and I have no idea what the string should be.

Comment: did you try putting 'true' in string or 'True'? in other components I see this is indeed a bool parameter 
https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/textarea

Answer (score 0):

draggable (string; optional): Defines whether the element can be dragged. draggable= 'true' will work. It is also possible to wrap a component under html.Div() and then add draggable property. For example,
html.Div([dbc.Input("Input here")], draggable= 'false', id = "input-div")